# Not able to receive Angular js events

Tags: angularjs

Please have a look at this simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgbpy/11/

I am not able to emit the event. I need to do this simple thing to do without creating  a shared service. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what @manoj was telling you

here is a fiddle that works

http://jsfiddle.net/tgbpy/13/

When you want to publish a message you call $rootScope.$broadcast unless the two controllers are nested. If you do $rootScope.$broadcast any scope wherever it is will get it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to broadcast less globally, but still hit where you are and its siblings, you can do $scope.$parent.$broadcast. (That also sends to the parent, obviously.) As it happens, I just put together a demo to clarify messaging with nested controllers for myself: http://jsfiddle.net/davemerrill/HQBFr/

Answer (score 2):

The controller1 and controller2 are are not nested. They are peers and come under the rootScope.

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">...</div>
<div ng-controller="controller2">...</div>
```

So when you emit an event from controller1, it wont reach controller2, but will only reach the parents(in this case, it will reach rootScope).

In case controller1 is declared within controller2, then your code should work.

```
<div ng-controller="controller2">  
  ..
  <div ng-controller="controller1">...</div>
  .. 
</div>
```